# FOSRestBundle add http basic auth

Tags: php, symfony, basic-authentication, fosrestbundle

I added FOSRestBundle to my symfony2 app, this app already had a public area and an admin area protected by FOSUserBundle.

My problem is, I don't get browser to prompt for user/password and also, when connecting api with `curl` I don't get authorized.

```
# app/config/security.yml
providers:
    user:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    administrator:
        entity: { class: App\UserBundle\Entity\Administrator, property: login }
```

Now I added an api area and want to use basic http auth, so added a new provider

```
    api_provider:
        memory:
            users:
                user1: { password: 1234, roles: 'ROLE_API_USER' }
                user2: { password: 1234, roles: 'ROLE_API_USER' }
```

And a new firewall:

```
firewalls:
    backend:
        pattern:        ^/admin/
        provider:       administrator
        anonymous:      ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/login
            check_path: /admin/login_check
        logout:
            path:       /admin/logout
            target:     /admin/
    api:
        pattern:  ^/api/
        provider: api_provider
        anonymous: ~
        # form_login: false # <- needed or not?
        http_basic:
            realm: "Api"
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            provider: user
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

At this point I leep getting a `403 - Forbidden`, so if I add this so `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/user, role: ROLE_ADMIN_USUARIOS }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/error, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/api/, role: ROLE_API_USER }
    - { path: ^/api/v1/users, role: ROLE_API_USER }
```

After this I get a `401 - unauthorized`.

I though http basic auth forced browser to prompt for a user/pass, which doesn't happen. Although, what I will finally need is the server to accept a basic auth header in http requests like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side).

I'm I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: If you solved your own problem, you may post it as an answer to your own question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Apparently the only way to invoke these urls now is through and http connection like `curl` adding authorization header, for example:

```
curl -u "user:pass" "http://example.com/app_dev.php/api/v1/users/1.json"
```

Accessing through the browser does not prompt for user/pass.

**Additionally**, a encoder was needed for the new provider to work properly:

```
# app/config/security.yml
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

Comment: I had to change `anonymous` to `false` too.